# How Can I Use Screaming Frog to Find Specific Text Using RegEx or XPath?

Tags: reporting, regex, screaming-frog

I'm using Screaming Frog to crawl my site. I created a custom search to look for "myterm". When i crawl the site, the reports shows how many occurrences of "myterm" are shown on each URL.

I want to take that a step further and also include the text that surrounds "myterm" in the report.

I was thinking a RegEx or XPath custom extraction could do the trick but all of the snippets I've used don't give me the results I want. The following is the latest RegEx snippet I tried. It seemed to provide good results but when I went to the website to verify, it missed some instances.

```
//text()[contains(.,'myterm')]
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I went wrong? Ideally, I would want the report to show 100 chracters before and after the "myterms" text. The 100 characters would include HTML as the crawler is looking through the code source of each page.

Comment: Why use a crawler?  If it is your site, you should be able to search the filesystem.  There are multiple tools that can do that easily including `grep` on the command line.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller good idea. I'm not too familiar with this CMS (Umbraco) or grep. How would this work? Would it search through the database of content?